# Is there a need to upgrade ubuntu one client in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I just tried doing a `sudo apt-get upgrade` in my 12.04 and I got this:

```
The following packages will be upgraded: 
audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 
libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 numix-icon-theme-circle 
python-ubuntuone-client synapse ubuntuone-client
```

Since [Ubuntu one is being shut down](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/), is there really any need to upgrade the `ubuntuone-client` or should I just purge it altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update includes a notification about the disconnection date for file sync, and prevents connecting to the server on or after June 1.

You can also safely purge the `ubuntuone-client` packages as well, if you just wish to remove the client and already have all your files downloaded, or plan to download them off the web site.